# Deploying Typescript Web App on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services

I need help with deploying a typescript web app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Here are some details about it.

1. I have it set up with a pipeline from GitHub so whenever I push changes on the branch, the changes are deployed on the app.
2. The Github repo stores my typescript files only and not my javascript files.
3. In the root folder I have two folders "dev" and "dist". "dev" contains the typescript files while "dist" contains the javascript files. ("dist" doesn't exist in the repo as the repo only saves .ts files). I have configured tsconfig.json with "outdir"

I need a way to make my EB server be able to build and then start my server. I have tried following blogs like this

https://medium.com/quick-code/how-i-automatically-deployed-typescript-to-elastic-beanstalk-to-speed-up-server-development-22b89870e159

and this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Where did you got stuck?

Comment: The steps in the article don't seem to work for me and beanstalk refuses to deploy changes.

What I am looking for is a way to
1. have a git hub repo with only ts files and not ts and js both (already done)
2. have a code pipeline that deploys changes automatically (already done)
3. have elastic beanstalk compile ts to js before running "npm start" (stuck here )